# How to parse array through controller in playframework

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing, playframework

I would like to parse array in controller. I know how to receive a string from view to controller. I am getting error when I am trying to receive array.

**View part:**

```
$("#save").click(function() {
var array;
    console.log("recorded");
      //get all the checked checboxex
      $('#tab input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        //for each checked checkbox, iterate through its parent's siblings
        array = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
          return $(this).text().trim();
        }).get();
 });
        //to print the value of array
        console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
         $.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.saveboxes()',
             data : {
                data:array
             },
             success : function(data) {
                alert("Success");

           },
             error : function() {

             }
              })
```

**controller part:**

```
public static Result saveboxes()
  {
Map<String,String[]> boxNumberFromView=request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
        String dept=boxNumberFromView.get("dept")[0].trim();
      System.out.println(dept);
return ok()
}
```

Please any one help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

try Using JSON.stringify before sending array to controller

```
$.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.saveboxes()',
             data : {
                data:JSON.stringify(array) // like this
             },
             success : function(data) {
                alert("Success");

           },
             error : function() {

             }
       });
```

**Updated**

```
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
  if(json == null) {
    return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
  } else {
    String name = json.findPath("data").getTextValue();
    if(name == null) {
      return badRequest("Missing parameter [data]");
    } else {
      return ok("Hello " + name);
    }
  }
```

Comment: super dude. Can you please tell me . How to parse the same in controller

Comment: you can directly Form.form().bindFromRequest().get("data");

Comment: Thanks bro. But its returning only first index. Can you please help me.